# Rational Visual test - Windows 8 - Error: Cannot set playback hook

Tags: windows-8, ui-automation, buttonclick, ibm-rational

I am running a suite of automated test written using Rational Visual Test for which there is no support currently. These tests were working great on a Windows 7 machine. We are now testing our product on Windows 8 machine. I was able to install the tool (Rational Visual test) on Windows 8. Some lines of code work fine, but I hit a roadblock when a test could not click on the "OK" button of a dialog box. This same test worked fine on a Windows 7 machine. the following error popped up in VT - "Cannot set playback hook". How do i go about debugging this let alone fixing this. Is this because some functions in VT are not able to access the Window APIs?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing the error message 'Cannot set playback hook' is that the exe files in the Visual Test folder (MSDEV.EXE, MT.EXE, MTRUN.EXE, MTSCREEN.EXE, MTVIEW.EXE and VCSPAWN.EXE) are not signed. Please look for a service or tool on the internet that can sign windows exe files. Once you have completed this process, copy the signed files into the Visual Test folder, overwriting the existing unsigned exe files.